# What is github project pages sites

Tags: github

What are github project pages sites, purpose of it. I read it is also known as gh-pages, how can i contribute or make commits to the projects which have these project pages. It is written on github that if you need to contribute towards a project the you have to open a pull request and merge the changes into gh-pages branch or change the branch. Could anyone explain what is gh-pages and how is it different from commits on other branches or the master branch itself

Comment: Did you read https://pages.github.com/? What specific questions do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a specialist of the question, but one difference I know is when it comes to host a jekyll website with github.

[Here](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/).

If you want to host your website in a folder of your project, you are in the case of a project page and need to be in a gh-pages.
It could be annoying, as in that case, the subfolder appear in the url.

Ex: [data-laborer.eu/blog/](http://data-laborer.eu/blog/)
(will be deprecated in a while)

If you want to host your website at the root, then you are in the case of a user page. You need to be in your `username.github.io` repository and in the `master` branch.

Ex: [data-laborer.eu/](http://data-laborer.eu/)

I am not aware of a difference when it comes to commit to a `gh-pages` or a `master` branch.